# Calculated Column Working Time with Lunch Break

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I hope, someone can help me finding the error.
I am working on a form in SharePoint to enter the working time. Calculating the working time without lunch is no problem, but I am running in Errors when including the Lunch time.

I have a choice-menu, where I can choose, how long the lunch time was (30 minutes, 45 minutes, 60 minutes, no lunch).

The columns are "WorkingTime", "LunchTime", "EndTime" and "StartTime".

My calculated column looks like below:

```
=IF([LunchTime]="No Lunch",((EndTime-StartTime)*24),
IF([LunchTime]="30 Minutes",((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-0.5),
IF([LunchTime]="45 Minutes",((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-0.75),
IF([LunchTime]="60 Minutes",((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-1))))
```

Can somebody tell me, where the error is?

Thank you in advance,
Best Regards
Jochen

Answer (score 2):

**Always** format you formulas in a Text Editor with line breaks,
and you immediatly see where you go wrong with the brackets:

```
=IF([LunchTime]="No Lunch"
    ,((EndTime-StartTime)*24)
    ,IF([LunchTime]="30 Minutes"
        ,((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-0.5
       )
    ,IF([LunchTime]="45 Minutes"
        ,((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-0.75
       )
    ,IF([LunchTime]="60 Minutes"
        ,((EndTime-StartTime)*24)-1
       )
  )))
```

You might want to do:

```
=(EndTime-StartTime)*24 -
    IF([LunchTime]="30 Minutes"
        ,0.5
        ,IF([LunchTime]="45 Minutes"
            ,0.75
            ,IF([LunchTime]="60 Minutes"
                ,1
                ,0
               )
           )
      )
```